# non static method getsupportfragmentmanager() cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static-methods, fragmentpageradapter

I got the following error while I calling the `FragmentPageAdapter` from static context android:

> ERROR: non static method getSupportFragmentManager() cannot be
>   referenced from static context .

```
ViewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
                                          myCategory, cxt));
ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.getCurrentItem());
slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(ViewPager);
```

Comment: You are trying to use this code inside a static method, and as the error says you cannot access non-static methods from a static context. So either remove the static word from your method, or consider refactoring your code in some other way so that this call will be performed from an instance context.

Comment: I know that but but here static method was needed that is why i put static any other way?,thank you @Orlangure

Comment: This is a bad advise, but you may create a static variable for your support fragment manager, assign it a value in your non-static method (onCreate?) and use it as a reference in new TabsPagerAdapter instead of getSupportFragmentManager() call. I strongly recommend you not doing so, but in that way your code at least will compile. Try refactoring your code to get rid of this issue instead of trying to solve it.

Comment: Show the relevant class and function code.

Comment: apart from the above mentioned by @Orlangure you can also pass a parameter `FragmentActivity activity` in the function in which this line occurs and use, `activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be sure from the code you posted, but it looks like you might have a Variable `ViewPager viewPager = ...;`, that you want to call `setAdapter(...)` on, but accidentally use upper case V in viewPager, which causes it to call a class method instead of an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think getSupportFragmentManager should be called with object reference as shown below not from static context like FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()

```
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(new FragmentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Answer (score -1):

In your static method, pass the activity as a parameter -

```
private static void staticMethod(FragmentActivity activity /*Any other arguments*/) {
    FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

    ....

}
```